# Example of Zend Form with Collection Element using Forms not Fieldsets in Zend Framework2

Tags: forms, element, zend-framework2

I need a straight forward working example how I can include a collection element in Zend Form, I have seen some examples from Zend Framework 2 [site](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.elements.html#collection-element) and from previous posts in StackOverflow where most of them pointed to this [link](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/?p=190). But right now I am not using Fieldsets and staying with Forms, so in case if someone can direct me in the right way, how I can include a simple collection element when the user gets a page where the user can choose multiple choices from the shown collection form. Much better would be populating the collection form from database.

I have searched in the internet for quite a sometime now and thought I would post here, so that Zend profis can give their suggestions.

Just For Information:
Normally one can include a static dropdownbox in Zend Form in this fashion

```
$this->add(
    array(
        'name'       => "countr",
        'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options'    => array(
            'label' => "Countries",
            'options' => array(
                'country1' => 'Brazil',
                'country2' => 'USA',
                'country3' => 'Mexico',
                'country4' => 'France',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

So I am expecting a simple example which could give me a basic idea how this can be done.

Comment: Your second link is dead. Please update it...

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't see your problem here. Since form collections extend `Fieldset` which extends `Element`, you can just add it to the form as a regular element. The view helpers will take care of the rendering recursively.

**Step 1:** Create a form collection (create an instance of `Zend\Form\Element\Collection`). If the elements have to be added dynamically in some way, I'd create a factory class for this purpose.

**Step 2:** Add it to the form. (For example using `$form->add($myCollectionInstance)`.)

**Step 3:** Render it. `Zend\Form\View\Helper\Collection` is a pretty good view helper to render the whole form without any pain.

You can also create a new class extending `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` and use the constructor to add the fields you need. Thus, you can add it to the form using the array you've pasted in your question. Also, you could directly use it in annotations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please give bit more brief example, as for my understanding it is better to look at some code (even basic is fine), because thats the way I can relate things faster. Hope im not demanding too much :)

Comment: is it possible for you to show in the form of the code example for this part:  "use the constructor to add the fields you need and you can add it to the form using the array". Your answer would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: I'll try this evening or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fill in a select list with option values you can add the array to the select list in a controller:

```
$form = new MyForm();
$form->get('countr')->setOptions(array('value_options'=>array(
                    'country1' => 'Brazil',
                    'country2' => 'USA',
                    'country3' => 'Mexico',
                    'country4' => 'France',
                ));
```

the array can be fetched from db.

this is a different example for using form collections in the simplest way.
In this example it creates input text elements in a collection and fills them in. The number of elements depends on the array:

```
class MyForm extends \Zend\Form\Form
{
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => '\Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'myCollection',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'My collection',
            'allow_add' => true,
    )
    ));
}

    class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
    {

    public function indexAction
    {
        $form = new MyForm();

        $this->addElementsFromArray($form, array(

                'country1' => 'Brazil',
                'country2' => 'USA',
                'country3' => 'Mexico',
                'country4' => 'France',
            ));

    //the above line can be replaced if fetching the array from a db table:
    //$arrayFromDb = getArrayFromDb(); 
    //$this->addElementsFromArray($form, $arrayFromDb);

    return array(
        'form' => $form
    );
    }

    private function addElementsFromArray($form, $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
        {
        $form->get('myCollection')->add(array(
                //'type' => '\Zend\Form\Element\SomeElement',
                'name' => $key,
                'options' => array(
                        'label' => $key,
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                        'value' => $value,
                )
        ));
        }
    }
}
```

index.phtml:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('home'))
     ->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form->get('myCollection'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```